# cannot recognize input near database SET LOCATION in alter database statement in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hdfs, data-warehouse

during a implementation, tried to change the HDFS path of an existing database in hive with,

changing the */apps/hive/warehouse/* HDFS path from specific path I am getting the following exception **as cannot recognize input near database SET LOCATION in alter database statement**
the database I have created is having the table table_mig created with it.

Please help on the rectifying the possibility and fix for this issue.
At this moment I am creating another database with LOCATION specifically with it as

**create database db_migg LOCATION '/sit/dwh/hdata/db_migg';**

````
hive> describe database db_mig;
OK
db_mig              hdfs://nnscbhaastest/apps/hive/warehouse/db_mig.db  hiveuser       USER
Time taken: 0.145 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> use db_mig;
OK
Time taken: 0.258 seconds
hive> show tables;
OK
table_mig
Time taken: 0.163 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> ALTER DATABASE db_mig SET LOCATION '/sit/dwh/hdata/db_mig';
NoViableAltException(26@[])
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterDatabaseStatementSuffix(HiveParser.java:10592)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterStatement(HiveParser.java:9028)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:4057)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1786)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1161)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:380)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:15 cannot recognize input near 'db_mig' 'SET' 'LOCATION' in alter database statement ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using an older version of HIVE. You need to have HIVE version 2.2.1, 2.4.0 or later. Please check the [hive wiki for more](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/Alter/UseDatabase).

If you are using lower version of hive, then try dropping and recreating the database with the alter location instead of using it in the ALTER script, as below:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_mig LOCATION '/sit/dwh/hdata/db_mig';
```

Comment: thanks it worked, sorry for the late acknowledgement.